# Name for sum of reciprocals

Tags: terminology

I have often run into the equivalent equations $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{c}$ and $c = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}}$ (e.g. [focal length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length#Thin_lens_approximation), [equivalent resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Resistors), etc). Does this relationship have a name?

Edit: wording

Comment: It's not a function, it's an equation with an infinite number of real solutions.

Comment: sorry, fixed. thanks

Comment: Such fractions are, if $a, b$ and $c$ are natural numbers, called Egyptian fractions. If I was to call the equation anything, it would be something like "Egyptian Diophantine equation" or "Egyptian fractional equation". But I don't think they have a commonly accepted name.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}$ is called a unit fraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes $2c$ is called the **harmonic mean** of $a$ and $b$. It is called the harmonic mean to distinguish it from the arithmetic mean $(a+b)/2$ and geometric mean $\sqrt{ab}$. If we write HM, AM and GM respectively for the means of $a$ and $b$, and we take $a$ and $b$ to be positive, then

$$HM \leq GM \leq AM$$

---

Comment: ah, I totally forgot about the harmonic series and the like. Thanks for all the info!

Comment: The [harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of $a$ and $b$ is $2c$.